# How to verify in app purchases in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, in-app-purchase, app-store, google-play-console

I am using [in_app_purchase](https://pub.dev/packages/in_app_purchase) in my Flutter app. The products are consumables.

I have followed the official example of package. But there is not logic for **verifyingPurchases**.
Right Now I am verifying the products with following checks.

```
bool _verifyPurchase(PurchaseDetails purchaseDetails)  {
if (purchaseDetails.status == PurchaseStatus.purchased &&
    _productIDs.contains(purchaseDetails.productID) &&
    purchaseDetails.transactionDate != null) {
  return true;
} else {
  _handleInvalidPurchase(purchaseDetails);
  return false;
}
}
```

But as **verifyingPurchases** is a very crucial thing. So I have doubt about it. I check on internet but found nothing great on how to verify Products in Flutter.The only solution is to use **RevenueCart**. But that is more essential for subscription or non-consumable products. Is there any logic that we can easily **verifyPurchases** in app?

Comment: It's best practice to validate from server-side, so validating it in flutter is not an option. Also, why don't you want to use RevenueCat? Their free plan is very generous.

Answer (score 1):

The logic for verifying the purchases is specific to your app. You should check that the content has been delivered to the user before verifying. This is a failsafe to ensure users don't request a refund for purchases that weren't delivered due to an unknown (perhaps devise specific) issue.

For example, if you have a product available to remove ads, then before verifying, you should check to see if the ad has been removed.

Example code for listener:

```
 void __updatePurchases(List<PurchaseDetails> data) async {

if (data.isNotEmpty) {
  // Add purchase data
  _purchases.addAll(data);

  // Handle any new purchases
  for (PurchaseDetails purchaseDetails in data) {
    if (purchaseDetails.status == PurchaseStatus.purchased ||
        purchaseDetails.status == PurchaseStatus.restored) {
      // Success, check delivery and complete purchase if purchase is not complete.
      if (purchaseDetails.pendingCompletePurchase && *your content delivery check here*) {
        _log.d("Completing purchase '${purchaseDetails.productID}'.");
        _iap.completePurchase(purchaseDetails);
      }
    } else if (purchaseDetails.status == PurchaseStatus.error) {
      // Failed, log error.
      _log.i("Purchase of '${purchaseDetails.productID}' failed.");
    }
  }

  // Query all products to get the details.
  ProductDetailsResponse response =
  await _iap.queryProductDetails(_availableProducts);

  _products = response.productDetails;

  // Notify listeners.
  notifyListeners();
}
```

}
}

Comment: I don't think this is correct, and may be misleading. Verifying purchase receipts is to defend against purchase fraud